# How do i get one temporary path from 'System.IO.path.getpath' in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am using `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath` to get the temp path link. But it retrieves more than one path, so that I was not able to create my file in the temp path.

Comment: _But it retrieves more than one path_ > Because in your OS you've more than one user accounts, isn't it ??

Comment: Try `Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also get temp path using
**My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp**